# Create/associate ssh keypair to an ec2 instance with the CDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm using the new Cloud Development Toolkit (CDK) to build an infrastructure on AWS using Java language.

I'm using a Bastion Host on a public subnet to communicate with an RDS instance on a private subnet, so I reach the database (on the private subnet) externally via an ssh tunnelling on the Bastion Host.

I've created the BastionHost in this way:

```
BastionHostLinux
            .Builder
            .create(scope, bastionId)
            .vpc(vpc)
            .instanceType(InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, InstanceSize.SMALL))
            .subnetSelection(subnetSelection)
            .instanceName(bastionName)
            .build();
```

I don't find any method to create or associate ssh key pair to the instance, so when I try to connect, aws tell me that I don't have any ssh key pair associated with the ec2 instance.

My question is: How can I associate an already existent keypair with an ec2 instance using the CDK? Or, (it would be better) how can I create a fresh key pair using the CDK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I associate an already existent keypair with an ec2 instance using the CDK?

There is no ssh key on bastion instance, if you want to ssh to it you should use `aws ec2-instance-connect`, look at [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ec2-readme.html#bastion-hosts) from aws CDK documentation. 
And here is a [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/new-using-amazon-ec2-instance-connect-for-ssh-access-to-your-ec2-instances/) which explains in more details `instance-connect`.

Comment: Yes, I have already read this. The problem is: to install ec2 instance connect on the bastion I have to connect via SSH to the bastion (as mentioned in the blog post that you linked, dot one), but how can I ssh connect to the bastion if I haven't the ssh keys? (In an automatic way, via the CDK)

Comment: If you do not have a specific reason for using `BastionHostLinux ` you could create an instance using `Instance` class and just give name of your existing key pair using `InstanceProperties`.

Comment: Yes I agree, I think the Instance is the best approach.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `addPropertyOverride` to set an existing key for the bastion host.

```
    const bastionSecurityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'BastionSecurityGroup', {
      vpc,
    });
    const bastion = new ec2.BastionHostLinux(this, 'Bastion', {
      vpc,
      subnetSelection: { subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC },
      instanceName: `my-bastion`,
    });
    bastion.instance.instance.addPropertyOverride('KeyName', `my-bastion-key`);
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer saved me hours of extra work. You are a legend. Cheers.