# AWS CDK EC2 Instance SSH with Keypair Timing out

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I've created an ec2 instance with AWS CDK in python. I've added a security group and allowed ingress rules for ipv4 and ipv6 on port 22. The keypair that I specified, with the help of [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041500/create-associate-ssh-keypair-to-an-ec2-instance-with-the-cdk/60043612#60043612) has been used in other EC2 instances set up with the console with no issue.

Everything appears to be running, but my connection keeps timing out. I went through the checklist of what usually causes this [provided by amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-resolve-ssh-connection-errors/), but none of those common things seems to be the problem (at least to me).

Why can't I connect with my ssh keypair from the instance I made with AWS CDK? I'm suspecting the KeyName I am overriding is not the correct name in Python, but I can't find it in the cdk docs.

Code included below.

```
vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "VPC", vpc_name=os.getenv("VPC_NAME"))

sec_group = ec2.SecurityGroup(self, "SG", vpc=vpc, allow_all_outbound=True)
sec_group.add_ingress_rule(ec2.Peer.any_ipv4(), connection=ec2.Port.tcp(22))
sec_group.add_ingress_rule(ec2.Peer.any_ipv6(), connection=ec2.Port.tcp(22))

instance = ec2.Instance(
    self,
    "name",
    vpc=vpc,
    instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
    machine_image=ec2.AmazonLinuxImage(
        generation=ec2.AmazonLinuxGeneration.AMAZON_LINUX_2
    ),
    security_group=sec_group,
)
instance.instance.add_property_override("KeyName", os.getenv("KEYPAIR_NAME"))
elastic_ip = ec2.CfnEIP(self, "EIP", domain="vpc", instance_id=instance.instance_id)
```

Comment: I tried changing "KeyName" to "key_name" as indicated in the CfnInstance code I found, but I got a "Encountered unsupported property key_name" error when deploying to aws. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/CfnInstance.html

Comment: Timeout doesn't mean issue with keypair. It's security group issue. Your instance has internet access?

Comment: Yes. When I look at the security group rules for outbound I am allowing all traffic and for inbound I have ipv4 and ipv6 open on port 22 (for ssh)

Comment: do 'telnet $yourec2ip 22'. If you get a timeout, it's intenet access. You can set up ssm access to login to it and troubleshoot.

Comment: That's a handy one to know. I did get a timeout, so I guess I need to figure out where the internet access issue is. However, I don't get how I can set up ssm when I can't get into my instance in the first place?

Comment: SSM agent is usually pre installed. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ami-preinstalled-agent.html ami's have it already isntalled. You just need to give extra policy for ssm to your instance role. Give the policies mentioned here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/setup-instance-profile.html.

Comment: I got pulled away from this, but I will get back to it soon if you want to keep an eye on the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with internet reachability, not your SSH key.

By default, your instance is placed into a private subnet ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Instance.html#vpcsubnets)), so it will not have inbound connectivity from the internet.
Place it into a public subnet and it should work.

Also, you don't have to use any overrides to set the key - use the built-in [`key_name` argument](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Instance.html#keyname). And you don't have to create the security group - use [the `connections` abstraction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Instance.html#connections). Here's the complete code:

```py
vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "VPC", vpc_name=os.getenv("VPC_NAME"))

instance = ec2.Instance(
    self,
    "name",
    vpc=vpc,
    instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
    machine_image=ec2.AmazonLinuxImage(
        generation=ec2.AmazonLinuxGeneration.AMAZON_LINUX_2
    ),
    key_name=os.getenv("KEYPAIR_NAME"),
    vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC),
)

instance.connections.allow_from_any_ipv4(ec2.Port.tcp(22))

elastic_ip = ec2.CfnEIP(self, "EIP", domain="vpc", instance_id=instance.instance_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need the instance to be in a private vpc. I thought the security group took care of allowing inbound from set IPs? This is what I did.

Comment: No, it doesn't. An instance in a private subnet cannot be reached from outside the VPC. You will either need to use SSM Session Manager or a Bastion Host that's in a Public subnet to connect through.

Comment: Hey @gshpychka, thank you so much for your help on this one. Sorry for the late reply. Your code works perfectly, and I think I can manage not having it in private a private vpc.